# Relationship between Ideals and subgroups ??

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am just wondering if Product of two Ideals is again an Ideal.

Let $I$ and $J$ be ideal of Ring, then is $IJ=\{ij: i\in I, j\in J\}$ still an ideal?

Answer (score 1):

No, $\{\,ij\mid i\in I, j\in J\,\}$ *generates* an ideal, which the smallest ideal that contains these product, and can be described as the set of all finite sums of such products.

In case of principal ideals, generated by $a$ and $b$, the product is again a principal ideal, generated by $ab$.

Comment: Thanks, Is ideal a subgroup under addition?

Comment: @Nancy: That's right.